# Pass an event as a parameter to a method

Tags: c#, events

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to pass an event to a method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2560258)

Is it possible to pass an event as a parameter to a method?

For example, the following method subscribes to the event, does work, and unsubscribes from the event:

```
void SubscribeDoAndUnsubscribe<TElement, TEventArgs>(
        IEnumerable<TElement> elements,
        ??? elementEvent)
    where TEventArgs: EventArgs
{
    EventHandler<TEventArgs> handler = (sender, e) => { /* Handle an event */ };

    foreach (var element in elements)
    {
         // Subscribe somehow
         element.elementEvent += handler
    }

    // Do things

    foreach (var element in elements)
    {
         // Unsubscribe somehow
         element.elementEvent -= handler
    }
}
```

Client code:

```
var elements = new [] { new Button(), new Button() };
SubscribeDoAndUnsubscribe(elements, ??? /* e => e.Click */);
```

If it's not possible, how do I achieve the similar logic in other ways? Shall I pass pair of delegates for subscribe/unsubscribe methods?

Comment: Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8022406/passing-an-event-and-a-delegate-event-handler-into-a-generic-helper-method/8022448#8022448

Answer (score 57, accepted):

You have in fact discovered that events are not "first class" in C#; you cannot pass around *an event* as data. You can pass around *a delegate to a method associated with a receiver* as a first-class object by making a delegate. You can pass around *a reference to any variable* as a (mostly) first-class object. (I say "mostly" because references to variables cannot be stored in fields, stored in arrays, and so on; they are highly restricted compared to other kinds of data.)  You can pass around a *type* by obtaining its Type object and passing that around.

But there is no way to directly pass around as data an event, property, indexer, constructor or destructor associated with a particular instance. The best you can do is to make a delegate (or pair of delegates) out of a lambda, as you suggest. Or, obtain the reflection object associated with the event and pass that around, along with the instance.

Comment: There is an exception to that rule: You CAN pass an event as a parameter to a method when the event you are passing is declared in the same class that is making this call. As in  class A{ public event SomeDelegate YourEvent; CallMe(SomeDelegate theEvent){theEvent(this,args); } }

Comment: @ILIABROUDNO: I don't see where in your little sample there `YourEvent` is ever passed to anything.

Comment: My bad. Put void in front of CallMe and then add another method to class A : void OtherMethod(){CallMe(YourEvent);} Now you are passing YourEvent as a parameter.

Comment: You are not passing an event, you are passing a delegate.

Answer (score 39):

No, unfortunately not.

If you look at [Reactive Extensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg577609), that suffers from a similar problem. Three options they use (IIRC - it's been a while since I've looked):

- Pass in the corresponding `EventInfo` and call it with reflection
- Pass in the name of the event (and the target if necessary) and call it with reflection
- Pass in delegates for subscription and unsubscription

The call in the latter case would be something like:

```
SubscribeAndDoUnsubscribe(elements,
                          handler => e.Click += handler,
                          handler => e.Click -= handler);
```

and the declaration would be:

```
void SubscribeDoAndUnsubscribe<TElement, TEventArgs>(
        IEnumerable<TElement> elements,
        Action<EventHandler<TEventArgs>> subscription,
        Action<EventHandler<TEventArgs>> unsubscription)
    where TEventArgs: EventArgs
```

Comment: You mixed `Click` and `Client` in your example.

Comment: In Reactive.Linq it is called [Observable.FromEventPattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/reactive-extensions/hh229705(v=vs.103))

Answer (score 4):

You're trying to get around type safety, and you can't do so without using reflection. I'll show you an even simpler example of what you're trying to do.

```
void DoSomethingOnSomethingElse(T obj, Action method)
{
    obj.method();
}
```

C# doesn't work this way. How does the compiler know that all `T`s have the method `method`? It doesn't, and can't. Similarly, not every `TElement` in your code will have an event `Click` for example.

It sounds like you just want to set a single use event handler on a set of objects. You can do this quite easily...

```
EventHandler handler = null;
handler = (s,e) => 
{
    DoSomething(e);
    var b = (Button) s;
    b.Click -= handler;
}

foreach (var button in buttons) 
{
    button.Click += handler;
}
```

This, obviously, only works with buttons, but as I write this, I see Jon Skeet has shown you a more general solution, so I'll end here.

Comment: Yep, you are right about type safety and reflection.